# Animating height of UITableViewCell iOS Static cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that this question has been asked 100's of times but I can't find a good fit for me. 
I'm using a `UITableViewController` with static cells. I want to be able to expand and collapse a certain cell programmatically, and I thought that animating it's height would be a good idea. But how can I do this?

I dont want to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` because my `UITableView` is static and I don't want to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because meny of my cells have different heights and I don't want to enter all of them and change them there every time I make a change in the storyboard.

I was hoping for a simple "Get cell and use `UIView animateWithDuration`" But can't find a solution for that.

What options do I have?

Comment: I think the best solution would be use heightForRowAtIndexPath: and reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With static table views, a UITableViewController has its own implementation of the datasource and delegate methods, where it reads the appropriate height from the storyboard file.

Override `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, and call the super implementation. This gets you the height as defined in the storyboard.

Then, for the index path whose height you want to modify, simply return your modified value.

To animate this change, call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` on the table view.

Comment: Thank you. That sound like a better alternative!

Comment: Super Implementation? I am new to this, do you have a coded solution by any chance?

Comment: @The-Rooster as in, calling `[super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`

Comment: The rows under the one I'm animating go to their new y value with a jump. Any idea how I can animate them too?